# Why I'm getting some strange drawings in the editor window some of the dialogs/sentences drawn one on each other?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first screenshot showing a written text "Serialized Property" but I'm not drawing it writing it anywhere in my script :

[image: serialized property]

The second screenshot show the bottom when scrolling down where the text is drawn one on each other :

[image: text one on each other]

This is the editor window script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    public static SerializedObject conversation = null;

    [SerializeField] private static ReorderableList conversationsList;
    private static ConversationTrigger _conversationTrigger;
    private static SerializedObject conversationTriggerSerializedObject;
    private static SerializedProperty _conversations;
    private static int _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;
    private static int newSize = 0;
    private static Vector2 scrollPos;
    private readonly static Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly static Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();

    [MenuItem("Dialog System/Conversations")]
    private static void ConversationsWindow()
    {
        const int width = 800;
        const int height = 800;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        var window = GetWindow<ConversationsEditorWindow>();
        window.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

        var conversationTrigger = FindObjectOfType<ConversationTrigger>();
        conversationTriggerSerializedObject = new SerializedObject(conversationTrigger);
        Init(conversationTriggerSerializedObject);
    }


    public static void Init(SerializedObject _item)
    {
        // Copy the Item targetObject to not lose reference when you
        // click another element on the project window.
        //conversationTriggerSerializedObject = new SerializedObject(_item.targetObject);
        conversation = conversationTriggerSerializedObject;

        // Other things to initialize the window
        _conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)_item.targetObject;
        _conversations = conversationTriggerSerializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");

        conversationsList = new ReorderableList(conversationTriggerSerializedObject, _conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            drawElementCallback = DrawConversationsElement,

            onAddCallback = (list) =>
            {
                SerializedProperty addedElement;
                // if something is selected add after that element otherwise on the end
                if (_currentlySelectedConversationIndex >= 0)
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);
                }

                var name = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var foldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                var dialogues = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                name.stringValue = "";
                foldout.boolValue = false;
                dialogues.arraySize = 0;
            },

            elementHeightCallback = (index) =>
            {
                return GetConversationHeight(_conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));
            }
        };
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (conversationTriggerSerializedObject != null)
        {
            //itemcopy.Update();
            conversationTriggerSerializedObject.Update();
            // if there are no elements reset _currentlySelectedConversationIndex
            if (conversationsList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1 < _currentlySelectedConversationIndex) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Conversations", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            {
                newSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField(_conversations.arraySize);
            }

            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                if (newSize > _conversations.arraySize)
                {
                    // elements have to be added -> how many?
                    var toAdd = newSize - _conversations.arraySize - 1;
                    // why -1 ? -> We add the first element and set its values to default
                    // now if we simply increase the arraySize for the rest of the elements
                    // they will be all a copy of the first -> all defaults ;)

                    // first add one element
                    _conversations.arraySize++;
                    // then get that element
                    var newIndex = _conversations.arraySize - 1;
                    var newElement = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

                    // now reset all properties like
                    var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                    name.stringValue = "";

                    // now for the rest simply increase arraySize
                    _conversations.arraySize += toAdd;
                }
                else
                {
                    // for removing just make sure the arraySize is not under 0
                    _conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(newSize, 0);
                }

                EditorGUI.FocusTextInControl(null);
            }

            scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));

            GUILayout.Space(10);
            conversationsList.DoLayoutList();

            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

            if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
            {
                _conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
            }

            if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
            {
                Undo.RecordObject(_conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
                _conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
            }

            //itemcopy.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            conversationTriggerSerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void DrawDialoguesHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Dialogues");
    }

    private static void DrawSentencesHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Sentences");
    }

    private static void DrawConversationsElement(Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        if (isActive) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = index;

        var conversation = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        var position = new Rect(rect);

        var name = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
        var foldout = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
        var dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");
        string dialoguesListKey = conversation.propertyPath;

        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
        {
            // make the label be a foldout
            foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 25, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, "Conversation Name " + (index + 1).ToString(), true);
            name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x + 145, position.y, 244, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);

            if (foldout.boolValue)
            {
                position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                if (!_dialoguesListDict.ContainsKey(dialoguesListKey))
                {
                    // create reorderabl list and store it in dict
                    var dialoguesList = new ReorderableList(conversation.serializedObject, dialogues)
                    {
                        displayAdd = true,
                        displayRemove = true,
                        draggable = true,

                        drawHeaderCallback = DrawDialoguesHeader,

                        drawElementCallback = (convRect, convIndex, convActive, convFocused) => { DrawDialoguesElement(_dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey], convRect, convIndex, convActive, convFocused); },

                        elementHeightCallback = (dialogIndex) =>
                        {
                            return GetDialogueHeight(_dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey].serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(dialogIndex));
                        },

                        onAddCallback = (list) =>
                        {
                            list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                            var addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);

                            var newDialoguesName = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                            var newDialoguesFoldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                            var sentences = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

                            newDialoguesName.stringValue = "";
                            newDialoguesFoldout.boolValue = true;
                            sentences.arraySize = 0;
                        }
                    };
                    _dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey] = dialoguesList;
                }

                _dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey].DoList(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
            }

        }
        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
    }

    private static void DrawDialoguesElement(ReorderableList list, Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        if (list == null) return;

        var dialog = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        var position = new Rect(rect);

        var foldout = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
        var name = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Name");

        {
            // make the label be a foldout
            foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 25, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, "Character Name ", true);
            name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x + 120, position.y, 244, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);

            var sentencesListKey = dialog.propertyPath;
            var sentences = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

            if (foldout.boolValue)
            {
                position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                if (!_sentencesListDict.ContainsKey(sentencesListKey))
                {
                    // create reorderabl list and store it in dict
                    var sentencesList = new ReorderableList(sentences.serializedObject, sentences)
                    {
                        displayAdd = true,
                        displayRemove = true,
                        draggable = true,

                        // header for the dialog list
                        drawHeaderCallback = DrawSentencesHeader,

                        // how a sentence is displayed
                        drawElementCallback = (sentenceRect, sentenceIndex, sentenceIsActive, sentenceIsFocused) =>
                        {
                            var sentence = sentences.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sentenceIndex);

                            // draw simple textArea for sentence
                            sentence.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextArea(sentenceRect, sentence.stringValue);
                        },

                        // Sentences have simply a fixed height of 2 lines
                        elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 2,

                        // when a sentence is added
                        onAddCallback = (sentList) =>
                        {
                            sentList.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                            var addedElement = sentList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sentList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);

                            addedElement.stringValue = "";
                        }
                    };

                    // store the created ReorderableList
                    _sentencesListDict[sentencesListKey] = sentencesList;
                }

                // Draw the list
                _sentencesListDict[sentencesListKey].DoList(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the height of given Conversation property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="conversation"></param>
    /// <returns>height of given Conversation property</returns>
    private static float GetConversationHeight(SerializedProperty conversation)
    {
        var foldout = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");

        // if not foldout the height is simply 1 line
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // otherwise we sum up every controls and child heights
        if (foldout.boolValue)
        {
            // we need some more lines:
            //  for the Name field,
            // the list header,
            // the list buttons and a bit buffer
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 5;


            var dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

            for (var d = 0; d < dialogues.arraySize; d++)
            {
                var dialog = dialogues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(d);
                height += GetDialogueHeight(dialog);
            }
        }

        return height;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the height of given Dialogue property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialog"></param>
    /// <returns>height of given Dialogue property</returns>
    private static float GetDialogueHeight(SerializedProperty dialog)
    {
        var foldout = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");

        // same game for the dialog if not foldout it is only a single line
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // otherwise sum up controls and child heights
        if (foldout.boolValue)
        {
            // we need some more lines:
            //  for the Name field,
            // the list header,
            // the list buttons and a bit buffer
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 4;

            var sentences = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

            // the sentences are easier since they always have the same height
            // in this example 2 lines so simply do
            // at least have space for 1 sentences even if there is none
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * Mathf.Max(1, sentences.arraySize) * 2;
        }

        return height;
    }
}
```

This is the conversation trigger script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditorInternal;

public class ConversationTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject canvas;

    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();
    [HideInInspector]
    public static List<int> conversationsToPlay = new List<int>();

    private DialogueManager dialoguemanager;

    private void Start()
    {
        dialoguemanager = FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>();
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayConversations()
    {
        canvas.SetActive(true);

        var conversations = conversationsToPlay.ToArray(); // Copy the list
        conversationsToPlay.Clear(); // Immediately clear the original list

        for (int i = 0; i < conversations.Length; i++) // iterate over the array
        {
            // Now you also don't need to remove items anymore, 
            // since you already cleared the list
            yield return StartCoroutine(PlayConversation(conversations[i]));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayConversation(int index)
    {
        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[index].Dialogues.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < conversations[index].Dialogues.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dialoguemanager != null)
                {
                    dialoguemanager.StartDialogue(conversations[index].Dialogues[i]);
                }

                while (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == false)
                {
                    yield return null;
                }
            }

            canvas.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Conversation Ended");
        }
    }

    public void SaveConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(conversations.ToArray(), true);
        File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json.txt", jsonTransform);
    }

    public void LoadConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json.txt");
        conversations.Clear();
        conversations.AddRange(JsonHelper.FromJson<Conversation>(jsonTransform));
    }
}
```

Sometimes it also showing in the edito some exception but I didn't save it and I can't to produce it. I will try and see if later it will show again.

I can't figure out what has changed. Something I changed and did wrong but can't figure out what. I tried to scan both scripts over and over again.

Comment: Either the value returned by `elementHeightCallback` or one of the used `Rect`s is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to why OnGui is terrible.

Comment: @Draco18s Is there any alternative for the ObGUI to work with in the editor and not while the game is running ? If I want to build a dialog system what other alternatives do I have to use then the OnGUI ?

Comment: No. Unfortunately.